# Clearing the text box after submitting the button in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces. I have to clear the text box value after submitting the command button.I have cleared the backing bean. Even-though the entered value in text box is displayed.please help me..

Comment: You probably need to put `update="idOfInputText"` on the button. If not, show some code

Comment: I used update also but even-though values are displayed.

Comment: If i use update the text box value is disabled but the popup is not displaying.

Comment: In update attribute i have to use form's id or textbox's id?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar this is my code <h:form id="searchForm" prependId="false">  
<p:inputText type="text" id="searchVal"            value="#{manageBean.searchKey}" />
<p:commandButton   style="height:28px;width:30px;" 
         update="searchForm:searchVal" oncomplete="Patient.show();" >
         
         </p:commandButton></h:form>